# Getting the Paypal developer documentation

Tags: paypal, documentation

Is the following link the correct place to look for Paypal developer documentation, or am I wrong?

> https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

All I get when I try to open the page is "The connection was reset" and "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

Alternatively, is there a PDF version of the docuentation, and could you please point me to tutorials or books to get started with learning the Paypal API?

Comment: It does appear that the documentation is down. However, questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal was down earlier today, should be available now. If not, clear your cache and cookies and you should be good.